# firefox top document position from top of screen

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on a Firefox add-on.
I need to get the position of the current top document from the top of the screen.
Do you know if there is a solution for it ?
Or, if its not possible, the height of all visible Firefox tollbars, includig tabs bar ?

Thanks you very much

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you the absolute offset to the top of the screen (in device pixels) of the `<tabbrowser>` that contains the website documents.

```
gBrowser.boxObject.screenY
```

There is also:

```
gBrowser.selectedBrowser.boxObject.screenY
```

which gives the same for the currently selected `<browser>`. It will usually yield the same value, unless some *clever* add-on adds some additional padding or other kind of spacing.

`boxObject` is a property of XUL-Elements and implements the [`nsIBoxObject` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/nsIBoxObject).

Comment: @user3429139 Thanking on SO usually involves either upvoting or accepting (checkmark) (or both) a helpful answer. ;)